# How do i change the value of a params query in an api?

Tags: reactjs, api, filter

I am puzzled on how do change the value of `params` in real-time like a `filter` algorithm on an API. Everytime I changes the value the requested data also changes when I put a string hard-coded on the `params` it response some arrays but when I use useState it does not .

```
import {React,useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form'
import List from './List'
import axios from 'axios'

const url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search'

export default function SearchField(){
  const {register ,watch, handleSubmit , formState:{error}} = useForm()
  const [query ,setQuery] =useState('bitcoin')
  
  const fetchQuery = async (e) => {
    try{
      const {data} = await axios(url,
        {params:{query: `{${query}}`}},
        {headers:{Accept: 'Application/json'}})
        console.log(data)
        console.log(query)
      }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchQuery()
  },[])
  return(
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
        <input {...register('coinSearch')}/> 
      </form>
      <List search={[]}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

as seen in the code above `query:` has variable of query but it does not changes the value.

P.S I'm trying to use `watch()` to read realtime the `<input>` but still nothing

Comment: Hi, when does `query` change? According to your code, the `fetching` is executed only when first loading, not when changing the `query`.

Comment: i want to change the value of `query` everytime I input a string I want to make it like a `filter()` but inside the APi and extracting the values that has the same string that I input

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `fetchQuery` and update the `useEffect` as followings to execute `fetching` when changing `query`.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  (async () => {
    try{
      const {data} = await axios(url,
        {params:{query: `{${query}}`}},
        {headers:{Accept: 'Application/json'}})
        console.log(data)
        console.log(query)
      }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  })()
},[query])
```

Hope this could fix your issue.